# Инициализация переменной в Java классе

Tags: java, инициализация

```java
public static class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    
    public void addFirst(T t) {  
        Node<T> firstNode = new Node<>(t); 
        firstNode.next = head; 
            head = firstNode;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        private final T value; 
        private Node<T> next;
    
        public Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, почему работает код. В методе addFirst есть строка firstNode.next = head. Мы присваиваем непроинициализированную переменную. И ошибки нет. Я понимаю, что head = null. Но почему если у нас есть некий класс Cat, то Cat cat; Cat cat2 = new Cat(); cat2 = cat, ,компилятор выдаст ошибку инициализации. Вроде как делаем тоже самое.

Comment: JVM выделяет память, заполняет её значениями по умолчанию (обычно нулями) и затем вызывает ваш конструктор. Если вы не записываете поле, в нём остаётся ноль. В случае локальной переменной (не поля объекта) такого механизма нет: компилятор следит что бы все локальные переменные были инициализированы **явно** до первого к ним обращения.

Answer (score 2):

Член класса

```
private Node<T> head;
```

инициализируется значением по умолчанию, в данном случае - `null`.

Локальная переменная

```
Cat cat;
```

не инициализируется.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @holya Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: отличный развёрнутый ответ. браво!